# Why backpropagation is done in every epoch when loss is always scalar?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I understand the backpropagation algorithm that it calculates the derivate of loss with respect to all the parameters in the neural network. My question is this derivate is constant right because the loss function is not changing. The weights are changing in every epoch but they are scalar values. The output of the loss function is also a scalar value. So why do we need to calculate the derivate(or backpropagate) in every epoch? I think if it is done once, it is enough and in the subsequent iteration or epoch we can just calculate its scalar value because calculating the derivate with respect to a scalar value does not make any sense.

Comment: Because the actual value of loss function depends on the value of parameters. As per [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function), "loss function... is a function that *maps an event or values of one or more variables* onto a real number". Thus derivative of loss function is also NOT constant and changes when parameter changes.

Comment: In practice, the sequence goes: 1) select an initial set of parameter values -> 2) compute the value and derivative of loss function at this set of parameters -> 3) take a step according to the derivatives, i.e. update the value of parameters -> 4) as parameter values changed, goes back to 2 -> 5) repeat 2-4 until stopping criteria is met.